# Render list action in modal sonata admin

Tags: twig, render, sonata-admin

I try to render the list action of my admin class in sonata in a modal, but I can't find the right way to do it?
Someone can help me please?
I just want the datagrid and not all the page(menu, topbar,etc...).
Actually i doing this like that :

```
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-toggle="modal"     data-target="#basicModal1">En Cours modal</a>
<div class="modal fade" id="basicModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"   aria-hidden="true">&amp;times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
               </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                {{render (controller('MonBundle:Controller:list',{'id':object.id}))}} 

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    </div>
```

But I've got this error with the render :

```
Error: Call to a member function getRelativePath() on null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whole page is shown because you are including a template of the standard controller action. Sonata use conditions for `app.request.isXmlHttpRequest` to detect if the view is opened in modal (via AJAX) or in a standard way.

So you may solve your problem by these steps:

1) Bind JS function (which opens modal) on button click.

2) When button clicked, load URL and paste its response body into `.modal-body`

URL: `{{ path('your-list-action-name', {'id': object.id}) }}`

It will solve the problem when you add a new record to the list from your page but list will show old records (because in your snippet, list renders once, on modal first render).

Additional info could be found in Sonata's ORM Admin Bundle (if you use ORM) under `Resources/views/CRUD/edit_orm_many_association_script.html.twig`